# return value for a static variable

Tags: c++, variables, static

I'm trying to use a static variable as a counter for the number of times a function has been called. Essentially, I'm having function A call function B a number of times, and I want function B to return that value to function A so it can be displayed. An example of my test code is below(here main is function A and showStat is function B). As of now the output is 012340; the desired output is 012344. Thanks in advance.

```
int showStat()
{

    static int statNum;
    cout<<statNum; //function check
    statNum++;
    return statNum;
}


int main()
{
    int statNum;

    for( int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++)
    {
    showStat(); 
    }
    cout<<statNum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The two symbols `statNum` are unrelated (and your code exhibits undefined behavior anyway). To change to the desired output, change the call `showStat();` to `statNum = showStat() - 1;`

Comment: Or change statNum to be a global static variable in the class and remove all other initialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In main, change

```
showStat();
```

to

```
statNum = showStat();
```

You have two variables called statNum. Apparently the counting takes place in the static variable inside showStat() function. But in main() without reading the return value of showStat(), you are just printing the uninitialized local variable, which the compiler happened to assign an initial value 0.

Comment: That'll produce the following output: `012345`.

Comment: @IInspectable his problem description was self contradictory. Yes the code will print 5 (different from 4 that he mentioned); but at the same time he said "count the number of times a function is called". His loop calls it five times.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I realize I should have had statNum++ before cout<<statNum. So, doing that and the above recommended change got me exactly what I was going for. Thanks again!